# Check if asp Checkbox is checked in a row of a GridView with Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a grid view and I want to see if the checkbox in the first column is checked. If the check box is checked it opens a new window. I cannot figure out how to see if the checkbox is checked. Please help the function below is not working and I can't figure out why.

```
function mapSelectedClick() 
    {
        var CustomerIDs = "";
        var grid = document.getElementById('<%=grdCustomers.ClientID %>');

        for (var i = 1; i < grid.rows.length; i++)
        {
            var Row = grid.rows[i];
            var CustomerID = grid.rows[i].cells[1].innerText;
            if (grid.rows[i].cell[0].type == "checkbox")
            {
                if (grid.rows[i].cell[0].childNodes[0].checked)
                {
                    customerIDs += CustomerID.toString() + ',';
                }
            }
        }

        customerIDs = customerIDs.substring(0, customerIDs.length-1);
        window.open("MapCustomers.aspx?CustomerIDs=" + customerIDs);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems in your code:

1. In both `if` conditions, you used `cell[0]` instead of `cells[0]`
2. In outer `if` condition you used `cell[0].type == "checkbox"`. Cell can't have type checkbox, it includes `chekbox` control as its child

Modify your function like this:

```
function mapSelectedClick() 
{
    var CustomerIDs = "";
    var grid = document.getElementById('<%=grdCustomers.ClientID %>');

    for (var i = 1; i < grid.rows.length; i++)
    {
        var Row = grid.rows[i];
        var CustomerID = Row.cells[1].innerText;
        var ctrl = Row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if (ctrl.type == "checkbox")
        {
            if (ctrl.checked)
            {
                customerIDs += CustomerID.toString() + ',';
            }
        }
    }

    customerIDs = customerIDs.substring(0, customerIDs.length-1);
    window.open("MapCustomers.aspx?CustomerIDs=" + customerIDs);
}
```

Note that `innerText` is not cross browser compatible, use innerHTML wherever possible.